# Only render specified view - CakePHP

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller, cakephp

I would like to render the view by itself, I want to avoid rendering the `<head>` and other sections defined in the default.ctp file.

I have the info that I want to render in an element:

```
<?php

echo $post['Post']['id'];

?>
```

How can I accomplish this? It is for an ajax response.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new layout (/app/views/layouts/ajax.ctp, for example) that contains:

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout ?>
```

Then in your controller, in the action you are using, define the layout:

```
function myaction() {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

Reference: http://book.cakephp.org/view/962/Page-related-Attribute-layout

Answer (score 1):

Just create a layout called `ajax.ctp` which only contains

```
<?php
echo $content_for_layout;
```

then in the controller put

```
$this->layout = 'ajax';
```

If you want to do this programmatically for all AJAX requests, just add the `RequestHandler` component to your controller

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler'); //and possibly others
```

and create a `beforeRender` method like

```
function beforeRender() {
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        Configure::write('debug', 0);
    }
}
```